# How to resolve "Access to requested resource is denied" Sith Amazon sp-api

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

When calling this url with Postman I constantly get this error:
https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/products/pricing/v0/competitivePrice?MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&Asins=B09WY3J32M&ItemType=ASIN

I have read, and re-read several times the appropriate docs, created the IAM and SP-API accounts.

I've tried using both VenderCantral and SellerCentral dev accounts/apps
I've tried using Role and User ARN's

any advice form anyone successfully using the sp-api competitivePrice call would be appriciated

Chris.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

expecting to see dative of ASIN product

Comment: You need to provide credentials to postman before you are able to retrieve/get the info. This api requires some sort of authorization - basic, bearer token etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex,I have added creds required by AWS including id, secret and added auth token as header. 

I have followed all SP-api docs but still fails

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi Alex, I get this:  {
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}